# How to implement a list of maps in Protocol Buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm looking to create a gRPC response that returns a list of maps. Here is what I imagined the structure being:

```
message GetSettingsResponse {
    repeated map<string, string> settings = 1;
}
```

Repeating maps is not supported, however, and  I had to nest the map in a separate message to make it work:

```
message GetSettingsResponse {
    repeated Setting settings = 1;
}

message Setting {
    map<string, string> setting = 1;
}
```

This works, but it forces us to write some confusing code on both the client and server. Is there any way to avoid this solution and get closer to my desired structure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, basically. What you have is the closest you can do in protobuf.

Comment: Is there a technical reason for this? If maps under the hood are just a key and value in a single message, why can't we repeat the maps? Referring to https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#backwards_compatibility

Comment: @Hansang because there would be no way of knowing where each map begins and ends; map is *already* essentially `repeated SomeKeyValuePair`, and the encoding format of protobuf doesn't support `repeated repeated` (jagged-style) - and cannot do so without changing the wire format, because the collection node (in the wire format) simply *does not exist* - just the child data; as such, there's no way of knowing where each inner group would be partitioned

Answer (score 0):

I came into a similar issue, that I'd like a Message corresponding to `List<Map<String,Object>>` in Java.

And I solved my problem by defining Message like this:

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message MyMessage {
    repeated google.protobuf.Struct mapList = 1;
}
```

Hope it'll help.